# Shopify's CartJS.addItem not firing success callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, shopify

Here's the code:

```
$('#add-custom-btn').click(function(e) {
    // add the item to the cart
    var varid = $('input[name=id]:checked').val();
    console.log('varidx: ', varid);
    CartJS.addItem(varid, 1, {}, {
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('finished adding item');
            $.get('/cart.js', '', function(data) {
                console.log('cart returned', data);
            }, 'json');
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that the [success](/questions/tagged/success) callback is not being fired at all. I've tested the get on cart.js, and it works fine. But I need to be sure the addItem has completed before calling that.

Comment: I think when using CartJS success needs to actually be a string `"success": function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)`. It is different from a success callback like in a get request. http://cartjs.org/pages/guide#core-api-adding-items

Comment: Yeah, that was how I had it at first. Both equally refuse to work for me.

Comment: Strange. I dunno, maybe try closing your addItem function before you start your $.get to /cart.js. Does your `console.log('varidx: ', varid);` print to the console?

Comment: Yes the `varidx` logs, but the `finished adding item` does not.  :(

Comment: Perhaps there actually is an error - try adding an "error" callback as well.